# Filter objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, filter

Is there quick way to filter an array of objects to return only a few properties in each object?

For example we have the data below:

```
var objArr = [{

    "Title": "July 13 - July 19 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "3,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "1.5",
        "tv_imp": "0.52",
        "Date": "2014-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 29
}, {

    "Title": "July 20 - July 26 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,600",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.55",
        "tv_imp": "0.052",
        "Date": "2014-07-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 30
}, {

    "Title": "July 27 - Aug 2 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.1",
        "tv_imp": "0.122",
        "Date": "2014-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 31
}]
```

I'm trying to filter the array above to get another array with only `videoAd_imp`, `videoAd_imp`, `tv_imp`. so it would look like this:

```
 [{

            "displayAd_imp": "3,500",
            "videoAd_imp": "1.5",
            "tv_imp": "0.52",
    }, {

            "displayAd_imp": "1,600",
            "videoAd_imp": "2.55",
            "tv_imp": "0.052",

    }, {

            "displayAd_imp": "1,500",
            "videoAd_imp": "2.1",
            "tv_imp": "0.122",
}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to modify the original objects, just loop over them, and use `delete` to remove the stuff you don't want. If you want new objects, use `.map()` and return new objects with only the stuff you *do* want. There's no built-in solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the object as is? (Not saying you should; just curious.)

Comment: ...is this data arriving as JSON data? If so, this can be done automatically using `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var objArr = [{/* ... */}];

// cache the array length to avoid resolving it on every iteration
var arrLength = objArr.length;
// your new array
var newArr = [];

for(var i=0; i<arrLength; i++){
    // push only the properties you want to the new array
    newArr.push({
        displayAd_imp: objArr[i].displayAd_imp,
        videoAd_imp: objArr[i].videoAd_imp,
        tv_imp: objArr[i].tv_imp
    });
}
// show it in the console
console.log(newArr);
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 9):

Use [*Array.map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like bellow

**If you want new references to all objects.**

```
var newArr = objArr.map(function (obj) {
     return {displayAd_imp:obj.displayAd_imp,videoAd_imp:obj.videoAd_imp,tv_imp:obj.tv_imp};
})

console.log(newArr);
```

**If you want to get original references use like bellow**

```
var newArr = objArr.map(function (obj) {
    delete obj.Date;
    delete obj.WeekNo;
    delete obj.Title
    return obj;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution

```
var newArr = []

for(var i=0;i<objArr.length) {
    newArr.push({
        displayAd_imp: objArr[i].displayAd_imp,
        videoAd_imp: objArr[i].videoAd_imp,
        tv_imp: objArr[i].tv_imp
       }
    );
}
```